# Rails, Sentry error reported on the get responses of API that is not allowed in some browsers including instagram browser

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, instagram, sentry, grape-api

my sentry report has received several errors on the use of API (Grape API) from the mobile users.

There is an API that is only accessible with post and put. However the request was made with get. One plausible way to send the request is by clicking the button (that sends request to the server via ajax) with some payload. However, in Sentry, there is no observed payload.

I'm curious why this kind of thing could happen. Where should I be suspicious of?

Thanks!

## sentry, #Rails, #request, #Jquery Ajax

Comment: Well, in normal cases I'd  use `before_action` hook in conjunction with `only: %i[create update]` but if you're creating something, you'll most probably want to call `new` action before it calls create, and that particular action uses `GET` instead of `POST`. That might be what you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my case, I am using Grape API where before action does not exist. There is an authentication part in the beginning of the code though.